# How to not conflict between policies on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I'm trying to make my AWS environment safer. So, I just created a **bucket**, **no modifications at all**, on `S3`, and want to give a **minimal set of permission to my application users**.
So, I have created an `user` called **keeper**, he can, basically, only **assume some role** that I can specify in his `policy`. And this is working because I have assume a role and requested a temporary session token for him via CLI. However, **in this role** I have **specified** a **policy** that, is possible to **upload** a file to a specific path, in my new `bucket`.

However, this is not working, giving me permission denied. Do I need to specify a **bucket policy** where it says that it's possible to upload an object to my path ?

If so, what is the meaning of roles then ? I'm a bit confused about resources policy and users/roles/groups policies.

Comment: A bucket with no policy works fine with this configuration. When a bucket policy is *also* present, its *deny* actions will defeat any *allow* in the role if they conflict (deny *always* wins), but the absence of a bucket policy essentially means "allow, only if allowed by another applicable policy." *"in this role I have specified a policy"* -- do you mean, the policy you submitted with the `AssumeRole` request, or the permission policy configured on the role itself?  If the latter, did you send a `Policy` with the call to `AssumeRole`? (You shouldn't.)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for your comment. I didn't specify a policy to my user to assume a role, I can just grant him as a `trusted-entity`.